# ScriptControl.AddCode without executing the code?

Tags: javascript, c#, vbscript, jscript, enterprise-architect

I'm working on a project in C# that get scripts (VBScript, Jscript and JavaScript) from the EA database and executes certain functions at specific moments.

To be able to do this I use the [Microsoft ScriptControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227633%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

First I add all script code to the ScriptControl using ScriptControl.AddCode and then I functions with a specific name.

The code that adds the code to the script control looks like this:

```
//create new scriptcontroller
this.scriptController = new ScriptControl();
this.scriptController.Language = this.language.name;
this.scriptController.AddObject("Repository", model.getWrappedModel());
//Add the actual code. This must be done in a try/catch because a syntax error in the script will result in an exception from AddCode
try
{
    //first add the included code
    string includedCode = this.IncludeScripts(this._code);
    //then remove any statements that execute a function or procedure because scriptControl.AddCode actually executes those statements
    string cleanedCode = this.language.removeExecutingStatements(includedCode);
    //then add the cleaned code to the scriptcontroller
    this.scriptController.AddCode(cleanedCode);
```

The problem is that apparently AddCode also executes the script code in some way, which is not what I want.

Say I have following VBScript:

```
sub main
    MsgBox("main executed")
end sub

main
```

As soon as I add the code of this script to the ScriptControl using AddCode the **main** sub is executed and I see the messagebox appear.

Does anyone know an easy way to avoid executing the **main** sub in cases like this?

My current workaround (currently only implemented for VBScript) involves parsing the script code and stripping the line that calls functions or procedures, but that is pretty tedious and error prone.

```
/// <summary>
/// removes the statements that execute a function/procedure from the code
/// </summary>
/// <param name="code">the code with executing statements</param>
/// <returns>the code without executing statements</returns>
public override string removeExecutingStatements(string code)
{
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(code);
    string cleanedCode = code;
    string line;
    bool functionStarted = false;
    bool subStarted = false;
    while (null != (line = reader.ReadLine()))
    { 

        if (line != string.Empty)
        {
            if (line.StartsWith(this.functionStart))
            {
                functionStarted = true;
            }else if (line.StartsWith(this.subStart))
            {
                subStarted = true;
            }else if (functionStarted && line.StartsWith(this.functionEnd))
            {
                functionStarted = false;
            }
            else if (subStarted && line.StartsWith(this.subEnd))
            {
                subStarted = false;
            }else if (!functionStarted && !subStarted)
            {
                //code outside of a function or sub, figure out if this code calls another sub or function
                foreach (string linepart in line.Split(new char[] {' ' , '(' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                {
                    if (cleanedCode.Contains(this.functionStart + linepart)
                        ||cleanedCode.Contains(this.subStart + linepart))
                    {
                        //found a line that calls an existing function or sub, replace it by an empty string.
                        cleanedCode = cleanedCode.Replace(Environment.NewLine +line + Environment.NewLine, 
                                                          Environment.NewLine + string.Empty + Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return cleanedCode;
}
```

Any better idea is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want the script code modules to act as code libraries without any static initializers then you can enforce it by declaring it in **coding conventions**
2. If you want the static initializers and other side-effects not to appear until the run-time then you can postpone the script activation through **delay loading** the script when it is required for the first time
3. If you want to have more fine-grained control over the scripting environment than you can **implement a scripting host** and interact with the script engines more directly (e.g. using the `IActiveScriptParse` interface will not probably trigger any unexpected side-effects).

   > [MSDN: Windows Script Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdee6589%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)
   >
   > ...To make implementation of the host as flexible as possible, an OLE Automation wrapper for Windows Script is provided. However, a host that uses this wrapper object to instantiate the scripting engine does not have the degree of control over the run-time name space, the persistence model, and so on, that it would if it used Windows Script directly.
   >
   > The Windows Script design isolates the interface elements required only in an authoring environment so that nonauthoring hosts (such as browsers and viewers) and script engines (for example, VBScript) can be kept lightweight...

Comment: 1. I don't have control over the scripts so I can't enforce any coding conventions. 2. I need the scripts right away, so I can't delay loading, and they shouldn't execute statements like `main` in any circumstance. 3. I'm afraid that will be my final option, but that will require serious rework. I still hope someone comes up with the miracle solution.

Comment: Although it was not the answer I hoped to find I had to accept this.  Sometimes the answer is "No it can't be done". In the end I stopped trying to modify the script, and instead selected only those scripts that I know to be written for my add-in because they contain the key word "EA-Matic"

Answer (score 0):

Main executes because you call it from a top level command. Anything not in sub/functions is executed.

Comment: @Serentity I'm aware of that. That is the reason why I'm stripping it out before adding the code to the ScriptControl. I'm looking for a way to avoid executing the code.

Comment: AddCode has to execute top level commands. It's how the environment is set. The Script Conhtrol is doing the right thing.